# vectorized implementation without using for loops

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement this code but it's quite slow because of two `for` loops. Can anyone suggest vectorized version of this code, please?

```
import numpy as np
P,Q = 1000,1000
thresh = 100
H = np.zeros((P,Q)
for u in range(P):
  for v in range(Q):
    if dist(u, v, P, Q) <= thresh:
       H_LP[u, v] = 1
def dist(u, v, p, q):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(u - p / 2) + np.square(v - q / 2))
```

Comment: Could you comment on what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Moosefeather it's implementation of ideal low pass filter in frequency domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```py
import numpy as np

P,Q = 1000,1000
thresh = 100

u = np.arange(P)
v = np.arange(Q)

dist_mat = np.sqrt(((u - P/2)**2)[:, None] + ((v - Q/2)**2)[None, :])
H = np.zeros((P, Q))
H[dist_mat <= thresh] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) can speed up your code

```
import numpy as np
import numba
```

```
P,Q = 1000,1000
thresh = 100
H = np.zeros((P,Q)

@jit(nopython=True)
def function(P, Q, thresh, H):
    for u in range(P):
      for v in range(Q):
        if dist(u, v, P, Q) <= thresh:
           H_LP[u, v] = 1

def dist(u, v, p, q):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(u - p / 2) + np.square(v - q / 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
P,Q = 1000,1000
thresh = 100
idx_H = np.stack(np.indices((P, Q)), axis=-1)
H_LP = dist(idx_H[..., 0], idx_H[..., 1], P, Q) <= thresh
def dist(u, v, p, q):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(u - p / 2) + np.square(v - q / 2))
```

Comment: Add description what did you changed/modified. Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: @Boken That's correct, but you reviewed this as "Recommend deletion". Code-only answers shouldn't be deleted, deletion is only for posts that aren't answers, like "thanks" or "I'm having this problem too". See [this post by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627).